# How to set attribute 'cross_tenant_replication_enabled' in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating Storage account using terraform and want to set *cross_tenant_replication_enabled* to *false*

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "data_resource_group" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example_storage_account" {
  name                             = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.data_resource_group.name #(Existing resource group)
  location                         = var.location
  account_tier                     = "Standard"
  account_replication_type         = "LRS"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public  = false
  cross_tenant_replication_enabled = false
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

I am getting below error

> Error: Unsupported argument
> on ceft_azure/main.tf line 55, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example_storage_account":
> 55:   cross_tenant_replication_enabled = false
> An argument named "cross_tenant_replication_enabled" is not expected here.

How can I set the attribute value to false?

Tried to set the attribute(cross_tenant_replication_enabled=false) in storage container block. But it didn't work.

Comment: You probably need to update to a newer version of the terraform provider for Azure.

Comment: @MarkoE, Thank you for your response. I am using latest version-3.0.1. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Latest version is 3.33.0:  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account

Answer (score 1):

Able to create storage account using terraform and want to set `cross_tenant_replication_enabled  as false`

Root Cause: **current version on AzureRM is not supported to cross tenant replication. Use azurerm >=3.0.1**
Update version in provider as

```
required_providers {
azurerm  =  {
source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
version = ">=3.0.1"
}
```

here is the code snippet
**Step1:
run below command**

```
terraform init -upgrade
```

**Step2:
Copy the below code in main tf file**

```
provider "azurerm" {
 features {}
 }
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg_swarna-example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "swarnastorageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type         = "LRS"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public  = false
  cross_tenant_replication_enabled = false
    identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

**Step3:
Run below commands**

```
terraform plan
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

**Verification:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Swarna for solution & detailed steps, it worked :)